# Display images with (post object) field type ACF

Tags: php, wordpress

I have  a ACF field group with post object field type. I have 8 products to display. I have displayed the title and permalink but can not display the product images. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('products_images');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
    $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post);
    $title = get_the_title( $featured_post);
    $custom_field = get_field( $featured_post);
    ?>
    <li>
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $custom_field); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
    </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php
    $featured_posts = get_field('products_images');
    if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
            $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post);
            $title = get_the_title( $featured_post);
            $custom_field = get_field( $featured_post);
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featured_post, 'full' );?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```